# JavaMail and Hotmail not working on Android

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail, hotmail

I am having trouble sending emails from a hotmail address using JavaMail.  I verified that I can connect to smtp.live.com via telnet port 587.  The interesting thing (to me) is if I change:

host = "smtp.gmail.com" 
t.connect(host, username, password);

It connects to Gmail just fine on the default port and sends an email.

But if I change the code to:

host = "smtp.live.com" 
t.connect(host,587, username, password); 
It gives me the following error:

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.live.com, port: 587;

nested exception is:

java.io.IOException: SSL handshake failure: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:604 0xaf076228:0x00000000)

With session.setDebug(true) I get this info:

09-15 01:57:37.280: INFO/System.out(720): DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.1]
09-15 01:57:37.300: INFO/System.out(720): DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
09-15 01:57:37.310: INFO/System.out(720): DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.live.com", port 587, isSSL true
09-15 01:57:37.330: INFO/SSLSocketFactory(720): Using factory org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl@4007ed70
09-15 01:57:37.490: DEBUG/NativeCrypto(720): SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 is set
09-15 01:57:37.538: ERROR/NativeCrypto(720): Unknown error 1 during connect

Looks like Hotmail isn't playing nice with OpenSSL.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

Below is my code in...just in case it helps.

Thanks in advance,

J

```
String host = "smtp.live.com";

String username = foo@hotmail; 

String password = "**"; 

Transport t = null;

Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");

//props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

session.setDebug(true);

try{

MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

msg.setSubject("Testing SMTP-SSL");

msg.setContent("This is a test", "text/plain");

msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));


msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,

InternetAddress.parse(username, false));

t = session.getTransport("smtps");

t.connect(host,587, username, password);

t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

} catch (Exception e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e.printStackTrace();

} finally {

try {

t.close();

} catch (MessagingException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

e.printStackTrace();

}

}
```

Comment: Try using the code tags [101010] around your code.

Comment: Done.  Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: did you already read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069966/connect-to-hotmail-with-javamail ??
does javamails smtp support ssl?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with sending emails to Hotmail/Outlook...

I solved it by adding the socket factory port always to 578 in your properties like:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
```

and for hotmail case the port is 25.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
```

A bit late but maybe it helps ;)